# why npm hangs on installing packages? hanging on idealTree

Tags: node.js, npm

I tried to use `npm install` in a react app but it hangs on  `idealTree:myProject: sill idealTree buildDeps` I have tried several things:

1-reinstalling node

2-removing or adding package-lock.json

3-using `npm i registry.npmjs.org`

4-`npm cache clean --force`

5-`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

I also tried `npm install --verbose` and [this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3GoZ.jpg)

beside that I even cant run `npx create-react-app myApp` and I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLwis.jpg) although I don't use proxy . so what should I do? apparently I can not use any npm package now.

**UPDATE** : I tried to change npm registry and set it to https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry. this time it started to install packages but at middle of it I got these errors

```
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at 
https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/@types%2feslint reason: 
Invalid response body while trying to fetch 
https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/@types%2feslint: Socket timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

*Probably your internet connection is slow, try with a fast network, hopefully, the problem will be solved.*

Comment: Thanks my friend the only think that I cant think right now is what you say

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that the problem is because of my network connection and some how I can not have access to *https//registry.npmjs.org.* and I manage to solve it and install packages with **yarn**. the only thing you might need to change if you can not install packages even with yarn is to change the registry try to use:

```
yarn config set registry https://registry.yarnpkg.com
```

also if after that you have problem with `npm start` or `yarn start` try to edit your `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
  "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build"
}
```